# Word 2010 Crashing

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

We have an office with all users using the same spec'ed PCs with the same Image deployed to them, so that the software and configuration is identical.

I have one user who keeps having the install of MS Word 2010 crash intermittently. First I reinstalled Office 2010 Suite, but will have the crashes.

The PC has been replaced with a clean install of Windows and Office but we are still having the issues with Word crashing.

We have had the user to log onto another PC which we know to be working fine, but again, Word keeps crashing.

Below is the Error from EventViewer:

```
Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 14.0.6024.1000, time stamp: 0x4d83e310
Faulting module name: MSVCR90.dll, version: 9.0.30729.6161, time stamp: 0x4dace5b9
Exception code: 0xc0000417
Fault offset: 0x000320f0
Faulting process id: 0xc34
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd1881ea917c33
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\MSVCR90.dll
Report Id: edd97602-8477-11e1-aa13-001111db42bf
```

The PC is running Windows 7 Professional and Office 2010
We have tried everything we can think of.
If anyone could enlighten us, it would be very much appretiated.

Cheers

Comment: Does this happen with specific documents previously saved by the user.

Comment: If this only happens to one user - did you consider to recreate his windows profile? I know it seems like a lot of work but it's often the fastest way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Langhard, user has mentioned that he has re-installed windows and have made user log into a different computer which is way better that creating a windows profile.

Comment: @vnodkumar1987 Only if this is not running in a domain with roaming profiles. Could very well be the case here. Btw. This one is super old...

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that this file is broken. First identify, which of the many possible locations of this dll is used on your system. Use Process Explorer and press Ctrl-D - look in the lower pane and identify the path. It could be something like

C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll

If you like you can do a binary compare of msvcr90.dll from another system: fc /B c:\temp\msvcr90.dll c:\temp\othersystem_msvcr90.dll

If the files are identical, then there must be another reason for the crash. We need a user dump to proceed and identify the cause. Use Procdump from

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900 and run

procdump -e winword.exe c:\winword.dmp

Start Word before you issue the command and let procdump run in the background until the crash happens.

If the files are different, try to reinstall the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package" and apply Windowsupdate again. You could even try sfc /scannow, but I'm not sure if the file is included in the check. At least the scanfile command failed in my test.
You can try to replace the file manually, but it requires some additional effort to circumvent the TrustedInstaller protection: Make sure, the file is not in use (Safe Mode), take ownership, add full permissions, ... (see http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-how-to-delete-files-protected-by-trustedinstaller/)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this could be caused by a file server move and the need to update the template location under the developer tab in word.

Add the developer tab by going to file > options > customize ribbon and check developer

Developer > Document Template > and update the address